# Gridgain Error Suppressed: class org.gridgain.grid.GridException: Failed to serialize object

Tags: gridgain

I am trying to put a key as String , value as List Intervals> in the cache and I am getting the below error. I have a put method in dao as generalised as object,object> so it can be used for difference cache

Input

```
[MAC4, [com.xx.Interval@1bccacc7]]
[MAC3, [com.xx.Interval@754b3232]]
[MAC1, [com.xx.Interval@78cf9e78, com.xx.Interval@6ad163f]]
```

MAC* is the key and List of Interval Objects are values.
Code:

```
 griddao.put("intervals",tuple.getValue(0),tuple.getValue(1));
```

In griddao

```
public void put(String cacheName, Object key, Object value) throws GridException {
                GridCache<Object, Object> cache = caches.get(cacheName);

                if ( cache != null ) {
                  cache.put(key, value);
                }
                else {
                  LOG.error( "Cache is null");
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to attach the actual error you got. Please provide full exception trace.

For now you can check whether `Interval` class implements `Serializable`. If it doesn't and you can't change it, configure marshaller not to require `Serializable` interface, like this:

```
<bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.gridgain.grid.GridConfiguration">
    ...

    <property name="marshaller">
        <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedMarshaller">
            <property name="requireSerializable" value="false"/>
        </bean>
    </property>

    ...
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks Valentin.. After I implemented Serializable to Intervals class, I got the below error: How do i add the class to the nodes?                  [05:15:27,030][SEVERE][gridgain-#55%sys-null%][GridCacheIoManager] <openintervals> Failed to process message [senderId=066898ce-7223-4977-98b2-0c1b155cc616]
class org.gridgain.grid.GridException: Failed to find class with given class loader for unmarshalling (make sure same versions of all classes are available on all nodes or enable peer-class-loading): org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheDeploymentManager$CacheClassLoader@4f543426

Comment: I also tried setting marshaller not to require Seializable as mentioned above, in this case the 'grid' is set as NULL and so the line GridCache<Object, Object> cache = grid.cache(cacheName) fails with NULL pointer exception. This does not happen when I dont set "requireSeializable".

Comment: I was able to figure this out. I had to add the jar to ../lib/ext so the class is serializable.